# Deadlocks c# Solution

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Hi guys I'm improving my knowledge of multithreading C# and  was wondering how to solve this classic deadlock issue.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private object _lock1 = new object();
    private object _lock2 = new object();


    public void Method1()
    {
        lock (_lock1)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            lock (_lock2)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        lock (_lock2)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            lock (_lock1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If two threads run simultaneously there is a risk of a deadlock.

Thanks

Comment: You solve it by never writing any such thing. If you have some situation that absolutely must do this for some idiotic reason and it cannot be reengineered, the threads should try the outer lock and if they can't take it immediately, go do other things and come back and try the lock again.

Comment: Maybe the article *No More Hangs: Advanced Techniques To Avoid And Detect Deadlocks In .NET Apps* at [MSDN](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineApril2006en-us.chm) may help.

Answer (score 2):

- Take your locks in a consistent order
- Keep your locks as granular as possible
- Avoid locks when possible by using immutable data structures
- Use Monitor.TryEnter instead of lock (which doesn't timeout)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a C# issue it is more general.
Your example is obviously not correct.
Try to avoid lock imbrication is the common pattern were you end up in a deadlock.
There a good book about synchronization:
 http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I'll take a look at that book.

Answer (score 0):

You must always take locks in the same order: first lock one, then lock two and so on.
You don't need to always take all locks: for example, you can have method1() take lock1 and lock2, and method2() take only lock2, it will not cause a deadlock.

Comment: Could you add some sample code to your answer, to phrase your response in the context that the question was asked in. A concrete example example is very useful.